# UseDisplayName is not working after renaming language code from fr-CA to fr

Tags: multilingual, link-manager

I have renamed language code from fr-CA to fr, Added fr version to all my content Items. Now the French name in the URL is not displaying? How to correct it?

Link Manager Setting:Web.Config

```
  <linkManager defaultProvider="sitecore">
  <providers>
  <clear />
  <add name="sitecore" type="Sitecore.Links.LinkProvider, Sitecore.Kernel" 
  addAspxExtension="false" alwaysIncludeServerUrl="false" 
  encodeNames="false" languageEmbedding="asNeeded" 
  languageLocation="filePath" lowercaseUrls="false" shortenUrls="true" 
  useDisplayName="true" />
</providers>
</linkManager>
```

SiteDefintion.config:

```
   <sites>
  <site name="sitecorelocal" patch:before="site[@name='website']"
        virtualFolder="/"
        physicalFolder="/"
        rootPath="/sitecore/content/Clsite"
        startItem="/Home"
        database="web"
        allowDebug="false"
        cacheHtml="true"
        htmlCacheSize="50MB"
        enablePreview="true"
        enableWebEdit="true"
        enableDebugger="true"
        useDisplayName="true"

        disableClientData="false"/>


</sites>
```

For the french language version pages, the french URL name should be displayed, As it defined the name in the DisplayName property.

Previously it was working fine with language code FR-CA, but after changing it to fr langauge code, The English is displaying in the french url.

How to fix it? I am using Sitecore 9

Comment: have a look here: https://sitecorecontextitem.wordpress.com/2014/08/08/changing-the-sitecore-language-format-in-the-url/

Comment: I did the same thing renamed Fr-CA to fr in system -language .but now the link manager setting use display name is not working English name of page is displaying it French url